# List of Default Translated Phrases

Tags: translation

With `<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>`, I know the phrase, "Save Changes" can be translated automatically if the user's locale is set to a different language. I'd like to know if there is a list of those already translated WordPress default messages.

What else can I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list is available in `$GLOBALS['l10n'][ $text_domain ]`.

To get the looong list of translatable WordPress strings just use:

```
print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $GLOBALS['l10n']['default'], TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
```

**Do not use these strings in your theme or plugin.**

They are internal, de facto *private*. They can change any time, even in minor updates. Always use your own strings only, even when you think: *this was stable for years!*

Recently the `HTML` tab in the post editor has been [renamed to `Text`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/21211). I wonder how many plugins will break now … :)

Comment: Have they changed the position of items in the array? This no longer prints anything :) The translations are in objects and some format like this, after I printed the entire Globals : `[data] => var TestL10n = {"language":"en-US","strings":{"Test":"Test"}};`

Answer (score 3):

Default wordpress translation files are available here:
http://i18n.svn.wordpress.org/

Here is an example with the french file:
http://i18n.svn.wordpress.org/fr_FR/trunk/glotpress/fr_FR.po

Use `msgid` like this: `<?php _e('msgid') ?>`