# How do I troubleshoot translation issues?

Tags: translation

I am building a WP site using the [Panoramica theme by CPOThemes](http://www.cpothemes.com/theme/panoramica), and so far most of it is working really well. However, not all translations work as they should (or at least not as I expect them to).

Specifically, I can't figure out why the header "Archives" on the main page isn't translated. The site can be found [here](http://hskammarkor.se) for you to look at - "Archives" is on the lower right.

This is what I have, that I thought would work:

- a file named `/wp-content/languages/sv_SE.po` (and .mo) that I have not changed, but I downloaded it and opened in [poedit](http://poedit.net) and the key "Archives" exists and is translated correctly.
- The code line that outputs the Archives header in the theme (specifically in `sidebar-home.php`) looks like this:

  ```
  <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e('Archives', 'cpotheme'); ?></h3>
  ```
- At the top of my `functions.php`, I have the following line:

  ```
  <?php load_theme_textdomain('cpotheme'); ?>
  ```
- Somewhere in `wp-config.php`, I have

  ```
  define('WPLANG', 'sv_SE');
  ```

Why doesn't this translate correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `'Archives'` translated in your text domain you have to load a theme translation `.mo` file. The file in `/wp-content/languages/sv_SE.po` will not be used for that.

- Create a directory `languages` in your theme.
- Add the translations for the theme to that directory. I recommend the [Codestyling Localization plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/) for that.
- Load the theme translations with:

  ```
  load_theme_textdomain( 'cpotheme', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
  ```

See also: [List of Default Translated Phrases](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62595/list-of-default-translated-phrases/62602#62602) for a way to inspect the phrases for a given text domain.