# Action hook load_textdomain $domain variable

Tags: actions, localization, translation, textdomain

I use the `load_textdomain` action hook to list all active localization text domains with corresponding path to translation files.

```
function mo_location( $domain, $mofile ) {  
    if ( !is_array($GLOBALS['moloc']) )
            $GLOBALS['moloc'] = array();

    $GLOBALS['moloc'][$domain] = $mofile;
}

add_action( 'load_textdomain', 'mo_location', 10, 2 );
```

For some reason the `$domain` variable is not filled with a "default" text domain values. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default` text domain is registered in `wp_load.php` before plugins are loaded. See the function `wp_load_translations_early()`.

So when you register your action callback, the text domain has been loaded already.

For an alternative way to list all registered text domains see this answer: [List of Default Translated Phrases](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62595/list-of-default-translated-phrases/62602#62602).

Comment: Yes, you are right! The thing is that I need cross reference domain with a corresponding translation file path. I use "must-use" plugin to initialize my code before all the translations are loaded. Do you think there is any better way?

Comment: @JohnnyPea you cannot run custom code before `wp_load_translations_early()` is called.

Comment: `wp_load_translations_early()` is not called during a regular load..."Designed for unusual load sequences (like setup-config.php) or for when the script will then terminate with an error, otherwise there is a risk that a file can be double-included."

It's enough to run it before `load_default_textdomain()` on line 268 in wp-settings.php